# Why isn't my custom authorizer Lambda function working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-authorizer

I have the simplest lambda authorizer for an HTTP API Gateway that should, in theory, allow anyone to access the protected resource. However, it doesn't seem to authorize *anyone*. In fact, I can't even get any Cloudwatch logs!

Here is the CDK code (Typescript):

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as apigwv2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigatewayv2'
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda'
import * as authorizers from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigatewayv2-authorizers'
import * as integrations from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigatewayv2-integrations'

export class ApigwCustomAuthLambdaStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const httpApi = new apigwv2.HttpApi(this, "HttpProxyApi", {
      createDefaultStage: true,

    })

    const authFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'BooksAuthorizer', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("handlers/auth"),
      handler: "auth.handler",
    })

    const booksAuthorizer = new authorizers.HttpLambdaAuthorizer('LambdaAuth', authFunction, {
      responseTypes:[authorizers.HttpLambdaResponseType.SIMPLE]
    })
    
    const booksFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'BooksFunction', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("handlers/books"),
      handler: "books.handler"
    })

    const booksIntegration = new integrations.HttpLambdaIntegration("LambdaIntegration", booksFunction)
    
    httpApi.addRoutes({
      integration: booksIntegration,
      methods: [apigwv2.HttpMethod.GET],
      path: "/books",
      authorizer: booksAuthorizer
    })
  }
}
```

and here is the lambda code for the custom authorizer:

```js
console.log('Loading function');
export handler = (event) => {
  const response = {
    "isAuthorized": true
  }
  return response;
};
```

Does anyone who knows about the subject than I do please enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong? I'm pulling hairs here.

Comment: It returns ``{"message":"Unauthorized"}``

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was caused by not using the .mjs extension, as exports can only be done from a ES module and not a regular .js file.

Also, I needed to add the Authorization header into the request. I used curl -H to do so.